# What is the probability the max of one sample is greater than the max of a different sample?

Tags: probability

Suppose you have two uniform distributions. To give an example, suppose there are $n$ values $x_i$ drawn IID from a uniform distribution $U[0,10]$ and $m$ values $y_j$ drawn IID from a uniform distribution $U[0,5]$. How do you find 
$ Pr(\max \{y_j\}_{j=1}^m \lt \max \{ x_i\}_{i=1}^n) $ as a function of $n$ and $m$?

Comment: They are maximums... over what? The answer clearly depends on how many samples we take from the first distribution and from the second one.

Comment: Sorry. Suppose a population of $n$ $x_i\sim U[0,10]$ and $m$ $y_j\sim U[0,5]$. So we're talking about the highest value in the population.

Comment: The random variable given by taking the maximum over a set of random variables with IID uniform distributions over an interval has a distribution which is a special case of a beta distribution; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases:

- If $\max_i x_i \le 5$ (which happens with probability $\left(\frac{5}{10}\right)^n$ since each $x_i$ must be less than $5$) then the conditional probability that  $\max_j y_j \lt \max_i x_i$ is $\frac{n}{n+m}$ since any of the $n+m$ observations can be biggest with equal probability.
- If $\max_i x_i \gt 5$ then clearly $\max_j y_j \lt \max_i x_i$ with conditional probability $1$.

So overall $$ P( \max_j y_j \lt \max_i x_i )= \frac{1}{2^n} \times \frac{n}{n+m} + 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} = 1- \frac{m}{2^n(n+m)}.$$

An alternative approach would be to look at $P( \max_j y_j \ge \max_i x_i )$, which is $\dfrac{m}{2^n(n+m)}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume we want to evaluate p(max(u,v)<=max(x,y). Then 
p(max(u,v)<=max(x,y)=p(u<=max(x,y)).p(v<=max(x,y)). Then p(u<=max(x,y))=p(x<=u<=y)+p(y<=u<=x)+p(u<=min(x,y))
=p(x<=u<=y)+p(y<=u<=x)+p(u<=x).p(u<=y). Then we proceed.